# Do I have to have a function triggered by .click when using the pulsate effect in jquery?

Tags: jquery, function, animation, pulse

I'm trying to figure out why this code

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
     $(".image2_template").effect( "pulsate", 
      {times:5}, 3000 );
  });
```

doesn't work yet this

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

  $("#text4").click(function(){
     $(".image2_template").effect( "pulsate", 
      {times:5}, 3000 );
  });

  });
```

work fine.  Does the pulsate effect have to be triggered by a click?  I want it to run on the page load.

UPDATE:
After listening to everyone's helpful suggestions I found out that the element is recognized as an object, but it is says there are no matched DOM elements when I use bjorn's mwthod.  How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: It should work fine. It does for me: http://jsfiddle.net/4hUkY/

Comment: It sound like the moment the DOM is ready your element is somehow not present in the DOM. Try a `console.log($(".image2_template").length)` in your `$(document).ready()` to verify the element is indeed present (the console should log a number higher than 0)

Comment: ok it returned a 0.  how can i fix this?

Comment: Well, make sure the element is present in the DOM before you initiate your pulsate effect. Hard to offer advice without knowing how/where the specific element comes from.

Comment: If this helps: the element is a dynamically loaded image, the source coming from an xml file.  i thought i could just use the class, but I guess I can't?  Should I assign the element an ID and what's the best way to do this?

Comment: Could you post the relevant code that dynamically loads the image? I'm guessing you're using `$.ajax` or `$.get` or something, if so, you can use the `success` callback function to initiate the pulsate effect once the resource is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not have to trigger it by an event such as click.
It should work as well just by calling the method.
[Here is a live example](http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/HMFpz/2/) of your working script.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong in this Script:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {    
          $(".image2_template").effect( "pulsate", 
          {times:5}, 3000 );   
       });
```

paste the HTML, maybe your ".image2_template" is rendering after , that is why it did not catch this

Comment: Have you changed anything from the code that was already posted in the question?

Comment: Am I missing something or isn't this exactly the same what the OP has?

Answer (score 0):

You have probably not selected your element properly. Try passing it to a var and then log it using your console to see if you have it properly selected.

```
var image_template = $(".image2_template");
console.log(image_template.length);
```

EDIT: Yep @Björn, your right. Edited it.

Comment: This will log `[Object object]` regardless of the number of elements matched (even if the element is not found, a transient jQuery object is still created and returned). Use `$(".image2_template").length` to get the number of matched DOM elements.

Comment: The console returns a 0 which means I haven't properly selected this element.  How can I do this?  Should I assign the element an ID instead of using the class?

Comment: Well you should provide some your html markup, so we can identify the error ;)